# How to find Eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the discrete cosine transform matrix by analogy method?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When I read the book "Introduction to linear algebra" 5th by Gilbert Strang,the example 6.5C give a method to guess the eigenvalues and eigenvectors by its analogy with the second differential equation，and I paste the picture of the example!

And my questions are:

1. How to get the eigenvalue of S?the book seems to omit some steps;
2. What is the relation between the eigenvalues $\lambda_{k}$ of S and the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of the ODE?

Thanks a lot!

[image: example 6.5C in the book"Introduction to linear algebra" by Gilbert Strang]

Answer (score 1):

This is only a tentative explanation as I am learning this book by myself. I interpret your two questions as one: how are the eigenvalues of S are calculated.

We first note that each row of S has elements (-1,2,-1) with 2 on the diagonal. These values happen to be the coefficients of a second difference equation, i.e. the discrete version of the second derivative. In other words, the equivalence $Sy=\lambda y = d^2y/dx^2$ may be guessed though the $=$ relation cannot be conceived as simple as indicated by this equation. We may, however, still safely guess that the discrete and the continuous version of the second derivative may share the same y. So we can obtain it by solving the ODE instead.

It is further noted that the shift of the positions of elements (-1,2,-1) with rows may indicate the shift of the difference $h$ used in the second difference equation $y''=(y(x+h)-2y(x)+y(x-h))/2$ towards one direction, say $2x$, when approximating the second derivative. This may give us the idea on the possible $y$s, i.e. the eigenvectors of S, as presented in the textbook.

Once the eigenvectors are guessed, we can plug them into $Sy=\lambda y$ to test the validity of the guess and if true, we should be able to determine the eigenvalues. Notice each row $i$ of S, $S_i$ times $y$ can be written as $$ -sink\pi(i-1)h+2*sink\pi ih - sink\pi (i+1)h=(2-2cosk\pi h)*sink\pi ih$$ where $sink\pi ih$ is $y_i$. As every $S_iy$ can be written in the same format $(2-2cosk\pi h)*y_i$, the common factor $(2-2cosk\pi h)$ has to be the eigenvalue.